# HtmlAgilityPack cant get string indexer

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

i want to parse HTML Using HTML Agility Pack

When i am searching index with int i am getting result.

```
HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/georgia/tbilisi");

var s1 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.HasAttributes && x.Attributes[0].Value == "ct");
```

But when i want to search atribute with string indexer i get an exeption.

```
var s2 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(a => a.HasAttributes && a.Attributes["id"].Value == "ct");
```

And when i dont use LINQ and use predicate delegate everithing is Ok.

```
Predicate<HtmlNode> pred = new Predicate<HtmlNode>(forpred);
List<HtmlNode> ss = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().ToList().FindAll(pred);
public static bool forpred(HtmlNode node)
{
   if (node.HasAttributes)
   {    
      foreach (HtmlAttribute atribute in node.Attributes)
      {
         if (atribute.Name == "id" && atribute.Value == "ct")
         {
             return true;
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}


//s1.ToList()[0].InnerHtml
//s2.ToList()[0].InnerHtml 
//ss[0].InnerHtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because some spans have attributes but not **id**. Your code can be like this:

```
var s2 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
         .Descendants()
         .Where(a => a.Attributes["id"]!=null && a.Attributes["id"].Value == "ct")
         .ToList();
```